# plot 3d surface with x+y<=1 in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a function surface with x_1 + x_2 +x_3 = 1.
Here I choose x_1 as x axis and x_2 as y axis.
To plot a 3D surface, the only way I know is to use meshgrid function. However, this will add points that x_1+x_2>1.

```
x_1 = np.linspace(0.1,1,num=5)
x_2 = np.linspace(0.1,1,num=5)
x_1, x_2 = np.meshgrid(x_1, x_2)
y.append(foo(x_1,x_2,1-x_1-x_2))
```

I cannot find a way to eliminate those points.
Would appreciate any help!

Comment: You are looking for a [masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_where.html#numpy.ma.masked_where). Mask `x_1` and `x_2` after generation with `meshgrid` according to your condition, and matplotlib won't plot anything there.